# PHP preg_match, how to capture only named regexs?

Tags: php

So this is the problem, Im using preg_match, to match current URI from browser, with the ones defined in my router.php config file. Im building Router/Dispatcher similar to Django.

What I want is that preg_match() captures only named regexs in $matches variable.

So If I have regexs like this:

```
^(?<param1>[a-z]+(?:\-[a-z]+)*)\.domain\.com\/[a-z]+(?:\/)?(?<param2>[a-z]+)?\/?$
```

Rubural link: [CLICK](http://rubular.com/r/OCsJxUVsmF)

When I compare current URI with this regexs it matches, but $matches variable returns this:

```
array ( 0 => 'sub.domain.com/page/pageurl/', 'param1' => 'sub', 1 => 'sub', 'param2' => 'pageurl', 2 => 'pageurl', )
```

Is it possible to tell `preg_match()` to return only named matches, and exclude those numeric one, what I would like to get is Associative Array :)

I could use `foreach()` and loop through $match and then inside check if its numeric or not... is there any better way?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't an `array_filter_keys` function, so you'll probably be best just doing the loop.

Comment: array_filter_keys can be done like: `array_intersect_key($matches, array_flip(array('param1', 'param2')))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find anything in the PHP manuals about named subpatterns in the first place, but I'm going to take an educated guess and say that you can't prevent the numeric keys in the resulting array.

The ground for this guess is that key `0` always contains the full match, and there's no way of naming that match.

If you want to strip out numeric indices, the best way would probably be a `foreach` loop.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php > `It is possible to name a subpattern using the syntax (?P<name>pattern). This subpattern will then be indexed in the matches array by its normal numeric position and also by name. PHP 5.2.2 introduced two alternative syntaxes (?<name>pattern) and (?'name'pattern).`

Comment: Thanks guys, il leave both indexed and associative values. Who knows who will be using this Dispatcher so its better to leave both options.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$namedFields = array_filter(array_keys($matches), "is_string");
```

Comment: The above didn't work for me. Instead, try :  array_filter($matches, "is_string",ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

Answer (score 0):

```
    $row = array_intersect_key(
        $matches,                     // 4. "filling" flipped key array with actual values
        array_flip(                   // 3. fliping array
            array_filter(             // 2. keeping string keys
                array_keys($matches), // 1. taking keys
                "is_string")));
```

also with php5.6 you could use array_filter

```
$row = array_filter(
    $matches,
    'is_string',
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
```